# When do Karnaugh Map terms make no groups?

Tags: dictionary, karnaugh-map

I understand how K-Maps work and what their utility is, but I can't seem to figure out under what conditions there could be no groups made. (When an expression is not simplifiable further? Won't it always be while speaking of canonical terms?)
Do help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) without simplified or merged blocks:

[image]

This example depicts the exclusive `OR` of four inputs `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
No pair of terms can be merged as none of them forms an adjacent couple.

Terms in a `Karnaugh` map correspond to a conjunctions (logical `AND`) of positive or inverted inputs. Two terms can be merged to one, if they exactly differ in the polarity of one input.

**Example:**

Term `abc` can be merged with term `abc'`.
The resulting term is `ab`. Input `c` can be omitted as it occurs with opposite polarity in the two original terms.

```
ab = ab(c+c') = abc + abc'
```

**Recommendation:**

My favorite online site to experiment with Karnaugh maps is [here](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/).

Answer (score 1):

These are the conditions to make groups obtained from [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/karnaugh-map-33):

1. Groups must be formed by combining 1, 2, 4 or usually 2n cells.
2. Cells can be grouped either in horizontal or vertical direction but not diagonally.
3. The cell having the zero value should not included in the groups.
4. Group must be as big as possible.
5. Overlapping of the groups are allowed.
6. Groups can be formed by wrapping around the grid.
7. No ones should be left alone.

So you cannot make groups for any situation not falling into any one of the above.

Comment: please consider adding some of the relevant info from your link to the space provided here.

Comment: My question was- when does an expression not follow any of the rules?